# Having difficulty with "For" loop + "setTimeout" logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, settimeout

Basic premise of my program is that I am trying to send an array of "http" request commands to different servers.

My path of thinking was to create a "for" loop and iterate through the array one by one sending all the batches of commands for each server in the array, but I am having a conflict where it appears that the "for" loop iterates all the way through and only sends the "http" request commands to the final server in the array due to the "setTimeout".

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could logic this out so that I can properly send the batch of httpcmds for each server while iterating through all the servers correctly.

Here is a sample of my code:

`

```
function sendHttpCmds(stbnum){
    var stb_num = stbnum;
    var xmlhttp; //cant make this an array of xml https

    function xmlsend(cmd){
        xmlhttp.open("GET",http[cmd],false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        }       

    for(var i = 0; i < stb_num; i++){ //this first loop is to iterate through the different servers
       var http = stb_prop.http_list[i];
       var httpLength = http.length;
       var lastIPcmd = stb_prop.ip_list[i];

       if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }else{
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

    for(cmd = 0; cmd < httpLength; cmd++){ //this second loop is to iterate through the httpcmd list that each server has
       (function(cmd){
            setTimeout(function(){
                //main command sent with 2 second intervals
                xmlsend(cmd);                  
            },2000*cmd);//set base delay ~1000-2500 ms
        }(cmd));
    }
}
```

}`

Just to clarify, stb_prop.http_list[i] is an array where each element contains an array of "http cmds". **Ex:** stb_prop.http_list[0] = http_cmds[]

Basically an array within an array (this is because i needed to dynamically create the list based on user input).

Comment: Either you are reading a pretty old tutorial, or you are supporting IE8-9. Otherwise drop the ActiveXObject ! [IE/Edge Platform status](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/xmlhttprequesttimeout?filter=f3f0000bf&search=XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with the http variable

Think about what happens, the first for loop starts, changes http and after exeuting a few commands the inner for loop starts to send all those requests. this happens asynchronously though. So imagine it is not actually executed until the outer for loop as gone through one more time.

This goes on and if you imagine none of the async calls are exectued before the outer for loop has completed, the value of http will be set to whatever the last server was. Now all the async calls execute, but they all use the last value of http instead of their own

A solution could be to pass http to the anonymous called function this way:

```
(function(cmd,http){
            setTimeout(function(){
                //main command sent with 2 second intervals
                xmlsend(cmd,http);                  
            },2000*cmd);//set base delay ~1000-2500 ms
        }(cmd,http));
```

and of course modify xmlsend to take in the http parameter.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: From what I've done it didn't change much of anything although I see what you are saying since I think it has to deal with the asynchronous sequence that the "for" loops are running especially because of the "setTimeout" that I am using.

Comment: I dont see anything else particularly wrong. One thing you could do is print out the content of http[cmd] in xmlsend to see if it's always what you expect. Also, no need to create an XMLHttpRequest every time, 1 XMLHttpRequest object will suffice, it doesn't have to be different for each request.

Comment: Did not know that! I thought that I had to create an array of them to ensure that I wouldn't be sending it all to the same server! Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: np, let me know when you find out what the problem is!